# Mantel correlogram outside of the range [-1,1]

Tags: coordinate-system, r, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation, logistic-regression

I want to represent the correlogram from the package `ncf` of the working residual `my_glm$residual` of logistic regression `my_glm` from `glm` function. When I represented it, I got a strange output that the Mantel similarity index sometimes is outside of the range [-1,1] (see the attached figure). I don't understand the problem here.

This is how I computed it :

```
knn <- spdep::knn2nb(spdep::knearneigh(xy_sp))
dist_class <- 2*(min(unlist(spdep::nbdists(knn, xy_sp)))) # double of the minimum distance between the sampled sites 
RESIDU <- my_glm$residuals
rnd_residu <- sample(1:length(RESIDU))
spat.cor <- correlog(xy[rnd_residu,1], xy[rnd_residu, 2], RESIDU[rnd_residu], increment = dist_class, resamp = 10,latlon = FALSE)
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
plot(spat.cor, pch=16, col="firebrick3", ylab="Correlation", xlab="Distance", main="Spatial correlogram", font.lab=2)
```

`xy_sp` represent a spatialPoints :

`Object of class SpatialPoints Coordinates: min       max x  467698.7  656887.7 y 5450967.1 5681736.1 Is projected: TRUE proj4string : [+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0] Number of points: 196`

[image]

Comment: Where does the `correlog` function come from? I can't find it in `spdep`, `spatial`, or `raster`. Please edit the question to show this, and also give us some information about `xy_sp` - perhaps just `summary(xy_sp)` or anything else useful. And what is `my_glm` and where does that come from?

Comment: I edited my post according to your questions. Thank you